# Incomplete type error when trying to create a BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher?

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, mingw

I have problem with [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/).

There are .h header files. Classes declared in this files look like this:

```
namespace ABI {
 namespace Windows {
  namespace Devices {
   namespace Bluetooth {
    namespace Advertisement {
     class BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher;
    } /*Advertisement*/
   } /*Bluetooth*/
  } /*Devices*/
 } /*Windows*/
}
```

When i want to create class, compiler raises me error 'allocation of incomplete type'.

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher* x = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();
```

What is going on. How should i use this? I have windows 10, C++ 11 and mingw compiler.

Comment: Just curious. Why would you compile standard Microsoft Windows SDK with mingw? If I am not mistaken it contains already compiler and linker. Also, what I see there ```class BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher;``` is a forward declaration. You can't use it to create class instances.

Comment: I am using clion, and it installed this compiler. Where can i find this oriper declaration. I want to get all ble devices, and i need this class. This code is in Windows. Devices. Bluetooth.h file. How can i get it?

Comment: You might consider switching over to Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition (which is a free download).

Comment: This is interesting. In all example code i have seen for ble devices, this header was included, but i am getting error. How this one works for evrybody, but no for me?

Comment: I was trying this vc, but to be honest its very bad for me. JetBrains had done better ide in my opinion. But even with vc, compiler must see declaration to work.

Comment: @Dragom3001 You can't use a forward declaration of any class with purpose to create instances of it, I already pointed but it probably this did not ring a bell. Also use Visual Studio, as PaulSanders suggest. There is no reason to use anything else when you can take full advantage of it. The community is well aware about what jetbrains is and what is visualstudio, it might surprise you, but better get used to idea.

Comment: Ok i got it, but my next question was where can i find this class then.

Comment: Try with VS, the problem might just go away.

Comment: Ok i will do it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher` comes with WinRT, not the Win32 API that MinGW provides.

So there is no way you will be able to compile that with MinGW/MinGW-w64 and you should try it with MSVC instead.